# How to terminate a function in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, function, exit

guys i have a problem in my jQuery code i wrote some code which makes a ajax request when a button is clicked but there is a problem when a button is clicked jQuery adds event listener for the yes to confirm button and also no when i click no it still listens to the yes button so when i click yes on some other button it submits the ajax request twice so i want to terminate the function when the user hits no button.

here's my code ->

```js
function confirmDelete(id, dataType) {
    $(".overlay").fadeIn();
    $(".confirmDelete").fadeIn();
    $(".confirmDelete").css("display", "flex");
    $(".overlay").click(function () {
        $(".overlay").fadeOut();
        $(".confirmDelete").fadeOut();
    });

    $("#confirmDeleteYes").click(function (e) {
        $(".overlay").fadeOut();
        $(".confirmDelete").fadeOut();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/delete/" + dataType + "/" + id,
            type: "DELETE",
            data: {
                _token: $('meta[name="csrf"]').attr("content"),
            },
            success: function (data) {
                activateNotificationSuccess(data.message);
                $(".closeSnackBar").click(function () {
                    $(this).parent().remove();
                });
                $("#" + dataType + data.id).remove();
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                activateNotificationFail("Something went very wrong !!");
            },
        });
    });
    $("#confirmDeleteNo").click(function () {
        $(".overlay").fadeOut();
        $(".confirmDelete").fadeOut();
        return false;
    });
}
```

Anyone has a solution?

Comment: why you have your event handler inside function ? Also , show your html code

Comment: Well i have them inside function because when the button gets clicked i just run this function which animates some elements and only then adds a eventlistener basically i want the event listener to be activated on button click.

Comment: Show relevant html code as well. Also ,move event handler outside function because that's causing problem in your code(submitting twice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Actually the problem is i'm nesting the click events so i just took it out the the first main click event and it works fine also i took all the code outside of the function. heres my final code ->

```js
let targetId;
$(".deleteButton").click(function () {
    targetId = $(this).attr("target-id");
    $(".overlay").fadeIn();
    $(".confirmDelete").fadeIn();
    $(".confirmDelete").css("display", "flex");
});

$(".overlay").click(function () {
    $(".overlay").fadeOut();
    $(".confirmDelete").fadeOut();
    return false;
});

$("#confirmDeleteYes").click(function () {
    $(".overlay").fadeOut();
    $(".confirmDelete").fadeOut();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/delete/" + "category/" + targetId,
        type: "DELETE",
        data: {
            _token: $('meta[name="csrf"]').attr("content"),
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            activateNotificationSuccess(data.message);
            $(".closeSnackBar").click(function () {
                $(this).parent().remove();
            });
            $("#" + "category" + data.id).remove();
        },
        error: function (error) {
            activateNotificationFail("Something went very wrong !!");
        },
    });

    return true;
});

$("#confirmDeleteNo").click(function () {
    $(".overlay").fadeOut();
    $(".confirmDelete").fadeOut();
    return false;
});
```